In JavaScript, how to create a date when given an OLE date format and keep it in GMT/UTC and NOT a local time zone using kendo?
I am struggling with keeping a date given to me in OLE date format, like what an Excel spreadsheet gives you for the value (i.e. it's a float value like: 40967.6424503935). Ok I get how to convert the date to a JavaScript date, but I have to keep it in GMT if the timezone is NOT specified. The Date() constructor is converting it to a local time, so when I finally convert it to the format I want it comes up in CST of course.


function excelOleDateToJavaScriptString(excelDateValue, format) {
    // Convert to a JavaScript Date object
    const jsDate = new Date((excelDateValue - 25569) * 86400 * 1000);

    var formattedDate = kendo.toString(jsDate, format); // given a format like mm-dd-yy
                                                        // it converts to local time.
    return formattedDate; 
}



I want to maintain the given date, and not my current timezone of CST.
If I give a date in OLE of like 01-01-24, it gets converted to 12-31-23 which is CST, the time zone I am in, great... I get that the JavaScript Date() constructor compensates for the current time zone and therefore sets it back to my current time zone.
Also, the format which is a string value can be ANY format that Excel deems as valid. I do not know ahead of time what that format string will be...and the requirement is to keep it in the format the user selects...we cannot convert it. So, no I cannot use the tried and true: toUTCString() or toISOString().
Any suggestions?

In new Date(number), the value is treated as millisecond offset from the ECMAScript epoch, so effectively UTC. When you stringify a Date, e.g. using toString, then system settings are used to calculate and display local values, hence you see CST. The Date itself doesn't have any concept of timezone.

RobG Ok then really I am stuck with using: Date.prototype.toISOString()... I think I can capture the date using this, and the database can put it in the associated format. Or what can I do to put it in as a given format (e.g: dd-mm-yyyy)?

There are many, many questions on formatting a date. If you just want a single format, then it only takes 3 or 4 lines of code so no need for a library. But if you have broader date parsing/formatting requirements, a library can help. There are many good ones, the Date object hasn't changed in decades (literally) so any of the popular ones will do, even if they haven't been updated in ages (because if it was well written in the first place, there's been very little need to update it).
